# Project Macro Exits Out Without Deleting All Relevant Tasks

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have a macro that I am using to delete all tasks that have a zero work effort if they are a) not a key milestone (enterprise defined field) or b) greater than outline level 1.

However, the macro exits out and does not continue to execute again all of the tasks that meet the criteria described above. The project plan is very lengthy (about 1840 lines) and it stops around line 200. It appears that the macro is not looping through all the relevant tasks but I can't figure out why.

```
Sub DeleteMsProjectTask()
Dim proj As Project
Dim t As Task
Dim tsk
Dim mileTsk
Set proj = ActiveProject
For Each t In proj.Tasks
If t.OutlineLevel > 1 And t.Work = 0 Then
   tsk = t.Name
   mileTsk = t.GetField(FieldNameToFieldConstant("Key Milestone?", pjTask))
   If mileTsk = "No" Then
        t.Delete
   Else
   End If
End If
Next t
MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

Comment: this is because you are deleting tasks while looping forward. You need to loop backwards when deleting tasks. Instead of looping with `For Each t In proj.Tasks` you need to loop with `For i = proj.Tasks.Count to 1 Step -1`.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

Code updated to delete tasks from subprojects as well.

As Shai Rado eluded to, the key is to loop through the collection using an index rather than iterating through the collection.

```
Sub DeleteMsProjectTask()
    DeleteTasks ActiveProject
    Dim sp As Subproject
    For Each sp In ActiveProject.Subprojects
        DeleteTasks sp.SourceProject
    Next sp
End Sub

Sub DeleteTasks(prj As Project)
    Dim NumTasks As Integer
    NumTasks = prj.Tasks.Count
    Dim idx As Integer
    idx = NumTasks
    Dim t As Task
    Dim mileTsk As String
    Do While idx > 0
        Set t = prj.Tasks(idx)
        If t.OutlineLevel > 1 And t.Work = 0 Then
            mileTsk = t.GetField(FieldNameToFieldConstant("Key Milestone?", pjTask))
            If mileTsk = "No" Then
                t.Delete
                NumTasks = NumTasks - 1
            End If
        End If
        idx = idx - 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!! Question - when I run the macro against a project plan without editing any of the data, it works perfectly (e.g. I have a project plan master template). However, if I manually manipulate any of the data (e.g. update the work effort hours for any tasks) the macro stops working and doesn't delete the tasks. Any thoughts on why this may be occuring?

Comment: @AJ123 Step through the code to make sure the macro is actually looping through the tasks of the project you expect it to be running on. Does it execute the t.Delete line and do nothing?

Comment: @RachelHettinger nice, I didn't have the time to write the code

Comment: @RachelHettinger It exits out of the macro when it hits the first section of the project plan that contains subprojects (so Level 4 on down - the project plan goes down to Level 9); but I'm not clear on why that would impact the ability of the macro to run because it works in the version of the plan where I have not made any manual updates.

Comment: @AJ123 You have subprojects inserted at level 4?? The code has been updated to handle subprojects. You need to loop through the tasks of each subproject separately and in addition to the master project.

Comment: Thank you Rachel, this macro worked successfully and deletes all of the tasks as expected. Appreciate the continuous help on this thread.